# Run keytool on php

Tags: java, php, cmd, keystore

I need a php script to generate *jks* with *keystore*.
What command should I use for it?

`exec()` or `system()`?

**My code:**

```
exec("keytool -genkey -alias 1800 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore 1800.jks -keypass brsacquiro -storepass brsacquiro 2>&1", $return_var);

foreach($return_var as $word)
echo "$word<br>";
```

I get result:

```
What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]: What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]: What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]: What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]: What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]: What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]: Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
```

I get ten of these texts in a row. I need to answer the questions that are listed there.
And at the end of this list I get **error**:

```
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many retries, program terminated
```

If I write this command in `cmd`, then all is ok.

Comment: Did you try your command on the commandline? Because this looks like a keytool error, not like a php problem that comes from `exec` vs `system`

Comment: I forgot to say. It produces results, but they are repeated many times. And at the end: keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many retries, program terminated.

Comment: If i write this command in cmd - all ok.

Comment: Did you try if your php user (www-data maybe?) can execute this command? Doesn't keytool create a file (key?), and if so, can it, or is it allowed in that location? Not sure why this error makes you ask a `system` vs `exec` question

Comment: ow, and please edit comments like about running the command to your question, it belongs there as necessary information. I'll add it, but keep that in mind: the question itself should be complete, comments are just more .... temporary-ish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no matter what to use, exec() or system(). Use this sample and replace ClientName, OrganizationUnit etc. with your values

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt \
 -alias alias1 \
 -dname "CN=ClientName, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, L=Locality, S=State, C=CountryCode" \
 -keystore keystore \
 -storepass password \
 -keypass password
```